# Error handling when implementing Admob for Android

Tags: exception, error-handling, admob, banner-ads

Since the new Admob SDK requires and uses the Google Play Services there has been several instances of widespread errors related to Google Play Services badly impacting apps with Admod as their monetization source.

There are some discussions open in the Admob Developers Forum in regards to how to mitigate these issues but I have not found a bulletproof approach to make sure that something like an Admob banner does not have a chance to force close my app if either Admob internal code or Google Play Services internal code breaks down.

Do you know of an error handling approach that in the worst case scenario would just maybe not load a banner add after it being requested instead of force closing the app generating an undesired low quality perception to the user?

Thanks,
Diego.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such beast.

Once you have invoked an async process (like ad handling) there is no way to catch that fault within your Activity.

Comment: Thanks William, are you perhaps aware of an alternative where catching the error was possible at the application level. If that was an option, then I have the choice to try to restore the session but call a different layout that doesn't include the banner instead.

Comment: You can intercept uncaught exceptions using `Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(handler)` but that point  you won't have any context to alter your layout or Activity. And if you do use `setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler`` make sure you keep a reference to the previous ExceptionHandler and hand off to it if it's no the Exception you are looking for.

Comment: Honestly I think you are worrying needlessly. I get about 1 crash from aberrant ads very 500K requests. You are better off improving the functionality of your app.